# Profile specific application.properties file in Spring boot and default injection of values for multiple profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

application.properties:

app.profile=${spring.profiles.active}
spring.profiles.active=dev

service.endpoint=${${spring.profiles.active}.service.endpoint}
service.api.user=${${spring.profiles.active}.service.api.user}

#### dev

dev.service.endpoint = https://test.google.com/ 
dev.service.api.user = /api/v1/user

#### prod

prod.service.endpoint = https://google.com/ 
prod.service.api.user = /api/v1/user

is there a way to further optimize this by removing common which in both env in this case value of **service.api.user**
so that rest of the values go to the default profile.

Answer (score 0):

How about this suggestion?
If You have properties of dev and prod, stg and have dev and prod is common but stg isn't common

application.properties

```
service.api.user = /api/v1/user
```

application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties

```
#service.api.user = /api/v1/user
```

application-stg.properties

```
service.api.user = /api/v1/stg
```

if when profile is dev, application-dev.properties don't have 'service.api.user'
spring find 'service.api.user' of application.properties